# Javafx Bug with Surface on high resolution

Tags: java, javafx, resize, resolution

I'm currently developting a Javafx application and have some problems with the resolution.

On my windows tower and on my Macbook everything works fine, but if I execute the application on my Surface with an resolution 2736 x 1824 everything is way to small.

At the beginning of the developing process the application was resizing automatically and looks good, but suddenly this resizing doens't work anymore. I suppose it has something todo with the Javafx Version.

Did anyone had a similar problem and know how to fix this?

Comment: If you think you have a problem with the JavaFX version don't you also think it would be a good idea to tell us which JavaFX versions you are using?

Comment: My bad! I am using Javafx Version 8.0.65

Comment: Then you should first try to upgrade your java to the latest version. Your version is years old and proper support for Hi-Dpi displays was added much later.